# Open ticket via email POP3 in Trac

Tags: pop3, trac, ticket-system

I'm searching for a way to let people open Trac ticket by email.

The only solution I've found so far is `email2trac` | https://oss.trac.surfsara.nl/email2trac/wiki The problem with this solution is that I don't want to install & setup a mailserver. I would like a less invasive solution.

I was thinking about a cron script that download messages from a POP3 account and open/update tickets by parsing the content.

Is this possible ?

Comment: Some useful discussion about this recently on the trac-users mailing list: [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/trac-users/Ujsf2WuG7Yc/l2Df0i-oj7AJ) and [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/trac-users/l9AQ57aCvgY/Fv5LmvtWoXoJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was thinking about a cron script that download messages from a POP3
>   account and open/update tickets by parsing the content. Is this
>   possible ?

I think it would be possible yes. Certainly once you had the data from a POP3 account, you could iterate over it and create/update tickets as appropriate with the Trac API.

For the data retrieval step, you could create a new plugin, with a [`Component`](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/ComponentArchitecture) which implements the [`IAdminCommandProvider`](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/PluginDevelopment/ExtensionPoints/trac.admin.api.IAdminCommandProvider) interface. How you actually retrieve and parse the data is an implementation detail for you to decide, but you could probably use the [email](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.html)/[poplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/poplib.html) modules and follow some of the parsing structure from [email2trac](https://oss.trac.surfsara.nl/email2trac/wiki/Email2tracParse).

For some untested boilerplate to get you started...

```
from trac.admin import IAdminCommandProvider
from trac.core import Component, implements
from trac.ticket import Ticket

def EmailToTicket(Component):
    implements(IAdminCommandProvider)

    def get_admin_commands(self):
        yield ('emailtoticket retrieve',
               'Retrieve emails from a mail server.'
               None, self._do_retrieve_email)

    def _do_retrieve_email(self):
        # TODO - log into the mail server, then parse data.
        # It would be nice to have a tuple of dictionaries, 
        # with keys like id, summary, description etc

        # iterate over the data and create/update tickets
        for email in emails:
            if 'id' in email: # assuming email is a dictionary
                self._update_ticket(email)
            else:
                self._create_ticket(email)

    def _update_ticket(self, data):
        ticket = Ticket(self.env, data[id])
        for field, value in data.iteritems():
            ticket[field] = value
        ticket.save_changes(author, comment, when)

    def _create_ticket(self, data):
        ticket = Ticket(self.env)
        for field, value in data.iteritems():
            ticket[field] = value
        ticket.insert()
```

You could then have Cron tab execute this command via [TracAdmin](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracAdmin) (the frequency is up to you - the below example runs every minute)

```
* * * * * trac-admin /path/to/projenv emailtoticket retrieve
```

The find out more about plugin development, you should read [this Trac wiki page](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/PluginDevelopment).

Comment: Your description is ok, but I was looking for something ready to install. I'm going to accept you question because it gave me few good inside.